# Ellipsize an horizontal list

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm building a browsing system, and it includes the usual breadcrumbs:

```
Home / dir1 / dir2
```

The breadcrumb list is a `<ul>` list. But when the list grows, it would be necessary to ellipsize it. The perfect solution would work this way:

```
|-- Width of the container's div ---|
 / Home / my / long / list / of / directories /
```

This would became:

```
|-- Width of the container's div ---|
 / Home / (...) / of / directories /
```

But I have no idea how could I achieve that. If I try to do it with javascript, I need to know the width of the rendered list, in order to know if I must ellipsize it. It sounds tricky.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: Show us the DOM or the  JavaScript code that creates it, and your current CSS

Comment: You can check compatibility here: http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-overflow"

Comment: @Kiz: The behavior intended by the OP is not what `text-overflow:ellipsis` does

Comment: @Bergi: It's just a plain `<ul>` list, generated from a [Google Closure template](https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/). The CSS is defined in the [Twitter Bootsrap breadcrumbs](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#breadcrumbs).

Answer (score 0):

You would struggle to do this the way you want with CSS.

I believe there's an:
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
CSS setting, but not sure on comparability across browsers.

Set it on the container and it would give you the (...) and truncate the breadcrumb to the width of the container.

Javascript will allow you to get the width of the container and width of the list, but I don't know how you would go about doing it I'm afraid.